# Unresolved attribute reference '__' for class '__'

Tags: python, class

I'm going through a beginner course and when I reached here the instructor made a separate file for the class and then imported it. I just added the class at the top because I've seen it work before. it doesn't work like this though but importing it from another file works. What am I doing wrong?

Full error message when running the program:

```
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/app.py", line 54, in RunTest
    ans = input(Class.question)
AttributeError: type object 'Class' has no attribute 'question'
```

```
class Class:

    def __init__(self, question, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer



QuestionPrompts = [
    "\n\n1. \na)\nb)\nc)\nd)\nYour Answer: ",
    "\n\n2. \na)\nb)\nc)\nd)\nYour Answer: ",
    "\n\n3. \na)\nb)\nc)\nd)\nYour Answer: ",
    "\n\n4. \na)\nb)\nc)\nd)\nYour Answer: ",
    "\n\n5. \na)\nb)\nc)\nd)\nYour Answer: ",
    "\n\n6. \na)\nb)\nc)\nd)\nYour Answer: ",
    "\n\n7. \na)\nb)\nc)\nd)\nYour Answer: ",
    "\n\n8. \na)\nb)\nc)\nd)\nYour Answer: ",
    "\n\n9. \na)\nb)\nc)\nd)\nYour Answer: ",
    "\n\n10. \na)\nb)\nc)\nd)\nYour Answer: "
]

questionArray = [
    Class(QuestionPrompts[0], "a"),
    Class(QuestionPrompts[1], "c"),
    Class(QuestionPrompts[2], "b"),
    Class(QuestionPrompts[3], "d"),
    Class(QuestionPrompts[4], "c"),
    Class(QuestionPrompts[5], "a"),
    Class(QuestionPrompts[6], "b"),
    Class(QuestionPrompts[7], "c"),
    Class(QuestionPrompts[8], "d"),
    Class(QuestionPrompts[9], "b")
]


def RunTest(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        ans = input(Class.question)
        if ans == Class.answer:
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Aww man, you got this question wrong therefore lost :(\n"
                  "You got " + str(RunTest(questionArray)) + "/10 right tho!")
    return score


print("Your Score: " + str(RunTest(questionArray)) + "!") #added this part to check if I absolutely need to call the RunTest from outside
```

Comment: You need to post the full error message / stack trace. It'll tell you exactly where the error occurs.

Comment: The *class* `Class` doesn't have an attribute named `question`; each *instance* of `Class` does. In your loop, `question` is an instance of `Class`.

Comment: You definitely don't want to call `RunTest` recursively.

Comment: @Ted-Klein-Bergman, I added the full error to the post

Comment: @chepner I'm sorry I don't get it, so what I have to do is to add an attribute named `question` and then refer to _that_ in the loop?

Comment: Replace `Class.answer` with `question.answer`, because `answer` is not a class attribute, but an instance attribute.

Comment: BTW, what you call `questionArray` isn't an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) but a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you need to first create an instance of that class,

Example:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...    def __init__(self,question,answer) -> None:
...        self.question = question
...        self.answer = answer
```

you need to first instanciate the class into an object:

```
>>> myobject = MyClass(question="how good is potato",answer="delicious")
```

then you can call the self.question:

```
>>> myobject.question
"how good is potato"
>>> myobject.answer
"delicious"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it out now

Comment: did it worked??

Comment: Thanks! I got this now

Comment: Ok, also can you mark this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a list of `Class` objects into the RunTest function.

When you iterate over this list, refer to the current object's `.question` and `.answer` attributes.

```
def RunTest(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        ans = input(question.question)
        if ans == question.answer:
```